# How to add Transition Animations on SharePoint Maincontent Placeholders

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

Has anyone done any work on Adding Animation on MainContent Placeholder. When you click on Left Hand Navigation(Quick Launch) i would like to animate the maincontent placeholder slightly from right to left.

Any Any one Suggest where do i start?

Comment: Do you need something like this link? Check the last option...http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/

Comment: That is True, how do i do that, do you have some sample css or jquery injection for that transition.